# How to read JSON file in PHP without using file_get_contents?

Tags: php, json, file, parsing

I've created a simple php file which reads a local json file and use the data to response to some queries sent to the page.

I'm using `file_get_contents()` to read the file. but as the requests count grown, I faced some performance issues because of concurrent connections to the file.

Is it possible to use `require()` or `include()` to read and parse the json file?

Comment: What you need to do is use a database instead of json files.

Comment: Read the file once, dump its content as PHP code (one of `var_dump()` or `var_export()`) that you simply `require_once` in your code. BTW, what are the parameters in your case? Requests per minute, size of the JSON, what you do with the data?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to create a caching system. It's probably better to just PHP serialize to a file, then unserialize as needed. Here is an example I wrote for a MVC framework I created and is in use on some clients production sites. https://github.com/SpeedyPHP/Framework/blob/master/lib/Speedy/Cache/File.php. I haven't ran any tests, but I'd imagine it's faster as it's not having to parse JSON (may be readable, but may not be as machine friendly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found some solution that fits, I'm now using `curl` to get the file contents like this:

```
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mysite/file.json');
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$jsonDataString = curl_exec($curlSession);
curl_close($curlSession);
```

Comment: If php script and json are located on the same server than this method is the slowest way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `require()`

```
 ob_start();
 ob_implicit_flush(false);
 require('test.json');
 $json = json_decode(ob_get_clean() , true );
```

but I think its not faster than `file_get_contents()`

The best way for performance is to load json-file to browser directly (e.g. by jquery) without php-parsing.